# Edittext : maxLength with limit 3 input numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I want to limit number of letter entry to 18 characters and also cannot use more than 3 number digits.

To limit the length I've already done my code but don't know what to do with 3 number digits.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/name_et"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLength="18"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890 @#$"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/name_tv"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: use can you text watchers in your code :)

Comment: @Umair, it is the only solution? I am familiar with text watchers but I thought this will be done by xml too

Comment: that can't be done through xml because you will have to check after every character entered that either your word has already 3 digits or not.

Comment: can you add solution in comment ? as I already tried with text watchers but not succedd

Comment: create regex with count

Comment: @AndroidGuy please check my answer. You will have to use regx to check the digits in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textWatchers` to check that user should not enter more then `three digits` in your `input field`:

```
           yourEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String numberRegx = "(?:\D*\d){3}";
                String currentString = yourEdittext.getText().length();            
                    if (currentString.matches(numRegex)) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid: " + input);
                 }else{
                        System.out.println("Valid: " + input);
               }
            }
        });
```

Comment: showing errors..
String numberRegx = "(?:\D*\d){3}";
Error :: Illegal escape character in string literal

Comment: @AndroidGuy the problem is with  `"\" (back slash)`. add 2 back slashes instead of one then try again ?   i.e `"\\"`